# Does an asynchronous replica in Always On Availability Group need to be part of windows failover cluster?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, failover

I have a Windows failover cluster up and running, with a primary and secondary server.

I have also created an Always On Availability Group with the two servers, with both the primary and the secondary replica being synchronous replicas.

I now want to add an additional asynchronous replica to the Always On Availability Group; to do so, do I need to modify the Windows failover cluster?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I now want to add an additional asynchronous replica to the Always On Availability Group; to do so, do I need to modify the Windows failover cluster?

Depends on how you want to do it. If you're adding an instance on another server, then that other server must be added to the WSFC in your current deployment as AGs can't span differing clustering environments.

If you don't want HA but DR/BC, then it's possible to not use a cluster by using read-scale AGs, which do not require clustering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added the third asynchronous replica to the always on availability group but I see it's in a disconnected state. Is this to be expected then, since it's not part of the failover cluster?

Comment: If it's not part of the cluster it's not even supported to run properly, let alone anything else. @Acuriousmind

Comment: Right, so the server has to be part of the failover cluster?

Comment: *If you don't want HA but DR/BC, then it's possible to not use a cluster by using read-scale AGs* could you please expand on how I could do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16 @Acuriousmind

Comment: So is it possible for a read-scale AG to coexist with the other AG I already have?

Comment: Yes they can coexist, but they can't be the same AG.

Comment: Can the same databases be synched for two different AGs?

Comment: "*databases can belong to only one availability group at a time*". How exactly can the read-scale AG provide DR?

Comment: They are a copy of the database, you always have DR. It's all in the Docs, I'd urge you to read them, they'll answer many of your questions.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it sounds like the easiest thing to do is to add the new node to the failover cluster (which I'm failing to do unfortunately, as described in my other question)

Comment: I ended up adding the instance to the WSFC. thank you